# extractLessThan operation on a singly-linked list with no tail pointer

Tags: c++

On a recent test this was a programming question that was asked.  I originally did not answer it correctly but I have edited my original solution and posted my new updated answer below the question.  I was wondering if I am heading in the correct direction with my solution or does my logic not make sense?

Implement an extractLessThan operation on a singly-linked list with no tail pointer.  Your code SHOULD NOT need to delete memory.  Your code must not call other LinkedList functions.  Order of the extracted nodes does not matter.

```
    struct LinkNode {
     Data * data; // note that you can compare by calling data->compareTo(other)
     LinkNode * next;
    };
    class LinkedList {
     LinkNode * head;
     /**
     * Returns a new LinkedList that contains all of the LinkNodes from this
     * LinkedList that has node->data->compareTo(value).
     * LinkedList * x = ... // x contains [5, 8, 1, 3]
     * Data * value = new IntegerData(4);
     * LinkedList * y = x->extractLessThan(value);
     * // x now contains [5, 8] and y now contains [3, 1]
     */

    // You have access to head and to this
    LinkedList * extractLessThan(Data * value) {
     LinkedList * newList = new LinkedList();
     LinkNode * current = head;
     LinkNode * previous = NULL;



    *-----------------------MY SOLUTION---------------------------------->

    while(current){
     if(current->data->compareTo(value) < 0){
       newList->head = current;
       current = current->next;
       return extractLessThan(value);
     else {return;}
    }
```

Comment: Ah man I hate these kinds of questions. I don't mean yours; I mean the one someone asked you. The reason I hate job interviews. Of what bloomin' benefit is this to humanity?! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinkedList *newList = new LinkedList();
LinkNode *newListHead;
LinkNode *prev;
LinkNode *current = head;  
LinkNode *next;
if (head->data->compareTo(value) < 0) {
    head = head->next;
    newList->head = current;
    newListHead = current;
} 
prev = current;
current = current->next;
while(current != NULL){
    if(current->data->compareTo(value) < 0){
        next = current->next;
        if (newList->head == NULL) {
            newList->head = current;
            newListHead = current;
        } else {
            newListHead->next = current;
            newListHead = newListhead->next;
        }
        current = next;
        prev->next = next;
    } else {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
return newList;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not even close. You can't take nodes from another list and plug them into yours and somehow think you're done -- you're destroying the original list. You can only copy the values, but each node has to be new and belonging to the new list.

Also I'm not sure why you're returning `extractLessThan(value)`. Even assuming this is the function and your dog just ate the definition, and ignoring the fact that you later return nothing, there's no need for recursion here. You already advanced to the next node: `current=current->next;`.